# regex to match after double forward slash until colon

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to match everything after the first occurrance of double forward slash until colon. The string looks as follows:

```
connectionUrl=jdbc\:postgresql\://somestringhere\:5432/somedb
```

So far I've managed to come up with the following:

```
/\/([^/])(.*?)(?=\\)/
```

This catches:

```
/somestringhere
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the second `/`, so that I only catch:

```
somestringhere
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "everything after the first occurrence of double forward slash" means you want `somestringhere\:5432/somedb`  but your example shows different. Be more clear about what you *really* want vs. what can actually show up in the string

Comment: What is the regex flavor? You might want [`//([^/:]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/yD3tP3/1).

Comment: hey, thanks for getting back to me so quick! I meant "everything after the first occurrance of double forward slash until colon" - I've edited the post. Btw, this is for powershell. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Powershell you may use a lookbehind and a negated character class based regex:

```
(?<=//)[^/:\\]+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zP1wX9/1)

*Explanation:*

- `(?<=//)` - a positive lookbehind requiring the `//` substring to appear before...
- `[^/:\\]+` - one or more characters other than `/`, `\\` and `:`.

[image]

Comment: Hey Wiktor, thanks for your input! Unfortunately, your proposal catches the following:

/somestringher

Comment: @AlfredoBonzo: it matches `somestringhere`. Do not let bad highlighting make you believe wrong. Read the explanation of my regex, or [see it here](https://regex101.com/r/eI3mX4/1).

Comment: hey Wiktor, let me test that out in real life and I'll get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Wiktor, tested this out in powershell directly and it still isn't matching what's expected:

$var = 'connectionUrl=jdbc\:postgresql\://somestringhere\:5432/somedb'
$var -match '(?<=//)[^/:]+'
$Matches.Values
somestringhere\

So the trailing slash gets matched as well unfortunately. I get the same if I use the regexstorm.net site. Thanks for trying nonetheless!

Comment: You should have explained from the beginning that the backslashes are literal backslashes  in your input string, this is very uncommon. I showed now hoe to match only up to the first ``\`` with just a negated character class. No need in a lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, here are two:
Using look behind assertion:

```
/(?<=\/\/)[^:]+/
```

Using a matching group:

```
\/\/([^:]+)/
```

===========================================

Let's say, you are working with **Ruby**:
Using look behind assertion:

```
str    = 'connectionUrl=jdbc:postgresql://somestringhere:5432/somedb'
regex  = /(?<=\/\/)[^:]+/
result = regex.match( str )[0]
```

Using a matching group:

```
str    = 'connectionUrl=jdbc:postgresql://somestringhere:5432/somedb'
regex  = /\/\/([^:]+)/
result = regex.match( str )[1]
```

===========================================

Let's say, you are working with **PHP**:
Using look behind assertion:

```
<?php
$str    = 'connectionUrl=jdbc:postgresql://somestringhere:5432/somedb';
preg_match( '/(?<=\/\/)[^:]+/', $str, $match );
print $match[0] . "\n";
?>
```

Using a matching group:

```
<?php
$str    = 'connectionUrl=jdbc:postgresql://somestringhere:5432/somedb';
preg_match( '/\/\/([^:]+)/', $str, $match );
print $match[1] . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Hey Andreas, thanks for your input! Unfortunately, your first option errors out (I'm using regexr.com for tests) having "(?<=" red underscored.

The second proposal red underscores the last "/"

Comment: @AlfredoBonzo: You should not use regexr.com if you really are using the regex in Powershell. Powershell supports .NET regex syntax, and regexr does not. You can rely on [regexher.net](http://regexher.net/tester) and [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to test .NET regexps, or download Ultrapico Expresso tool.

Comment: Hey Alfredo: To test my regular expressions on regexr.com, you have to omit the delimiter (the leading as well as the trailing slash "/"). The first regex still errors out on regexr.com, because apparently, regexr.com does NOT support (look behind) assertions. Every regexp-flavor has its differences...

Comment: Hey Andreas, sadly none of them work in powershell as expected - it's always a match with trailing slash, so "somestringhere\", but thanks for trying!

Comment: No worries, buddy! My solutions were not meant for or tested in Powershell, as, your question did not define that. My solutions were tested in Ruby and Php, but would surely also work in similar programming languages and Regex flavors. Personally, I'm not familiar with Powershell. Nevertheless, I'm happy, you were able to solve your problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

```
$string = "connectionUrl=jdbc\:postgresql\://somestringhere\:5432/somedb"

if ($string -match '^.*\/\/(.+)\\:')
{
    $Matches[1]
}
```

Output:

```
somestringhere
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something a simple `'//(.*?)\\:'` should suffice. Also, if you do anchor the expression at the beginning of the string you *must* make that part of the match non-greedy (`^.*?`), otherwise you'll be matching the last occurrence of `//(.+)\\:` rather than the first one.

Comment: Hey Micky - that did it! All 3 proposals work as expected. I'm wondering if there's a way to narrow this down to just one final match, rather than two matches and then being forced to specify the one with index 1...

Comment: @AlfredoBonzo `$Matches[0]` contains the complete match (`connectionUrl=jdbc\:postgresql\://somestringhere\:`), but you want just the grouped submatch, thus you need `$Matches[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on the input from Wiktor, Micky and Andreas (cheers!), I've experimented a bit and in the end achieved the desired match using the following regex in powershell:

```
(?<=//)[^/:]+(?=\\)
```

Test results:

```
$var = 'connectionUrl=jdbc:postgresql://somestringhere:5432/somedb'
$var -match '(?<=//)[^/:]+(?=\\)'
$Matches.Values
somestringhere
```

Once again, thank you all for combining your efforts here!

Comment: It was unclear from the start whether the backslashes are part of a C string, or literal ``\`` symbols. I understand it now. You do not need the lookahead.